# HTML5 Bootstrap - Keeping text in a div within an image

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

**HTML**

```
<div class="tag">TEXT<br> <a href="#bottom"class="icons glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down"></a></div>
<img src="images/flower.jpg" class ="img-responsive" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
```

**CSS**

```
.tag {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 50px;
    z-index: 1000;
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    max-width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #222222;
    font-size:75px;
}
```

When I adjust the size of the page to a mobile size, the text on top of the image doesn't resize too and insteads covers the rest of the webpage.

Example: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/08v4sg4L/6/)

^ As you drag the window smaller, the text overlaps the body text.

Answer (score 0):

You are not even targeting img, You should use,

```
img { width: 100% }
```

And put text inside p tag or h3 tag,

```
h3 { font-size: 1em} // or 1rem
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to change your font-size on smaller screens

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .tag {
     font-size: 20px;
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.